# Error function is not defined in class in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have interface like below.

```
@interface HistoryShow : UIViewController {
}

-(IBAction) listTableViewController:(id) sender;  

@end
```

and my implementation is here

```
-(IBAction) listTableViewController:(id) sender {

    NSLog(@"Loaded");
    NSLog(@"FFFFFFFFFFF");
}
```

and i have connected this function to File's Manager but i am seeing a warning on Inspector screen is function "listTableViewController" is no longer defined in "HistoryShow". It seems to defined perfectly. What is wrong with me ?
thanks

Comment: 74 questions, you need http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I just write another function and connected with the files Manager now i am getting an error "Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”." on Console screen. when i am clicking on button and want to print output on console.

Comment: come online on chat in objective c group i will tell u

Comment: @Marvin: Why don't you "tell him" down there in the answer area?

Comment: @BoltClock : because I want to tell him everything and let him know about how to connect button's event from interface builder...and I think I am not disturbing you...

Comment: @marvin Please put answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try performing a clean and build.

Comment: Yes i did.Why i am getting bad access when i am trying to connect with function on button event call ?

Comment: Try setting NSZombie environment variable. Or try to debug your application